# Authenticating / Refreshing Google API access token and avoiding a "file in use" exception?

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

This is how I authenticate for using the Google API:

```
Private Function DoAuthentication(ByRef rStrToken As String, ByRef rParameters As OAuth2Parameters) As Boolean
    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets() With {
        .ClientId = m_strClientID,
        .ClientSecret = m_strClientSecret
    }

    m_Scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)

    Try
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, m_Scopes,
                                                                 "user", CancellationToken.None,
                                                                 New FileDataStore("XXXXX.Application")).Result()

        If credential.Token.IsExpired(Google.Apis.Util.SystemClock.Default) Then
            credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None)
        End If


        ' Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
        Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
            .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            .ApplicationName = "xxx"
        }
        m_Service = New CalendarService(initializer)

        rStrToken = credential.Token.AccessToken.ToString()
        rParameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken
        rParameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' We encountered some kind of problem, perhaps they have not yet authenticated?
        ' Can we isolate that as the exception?
        m_logger.Error(ex, "DoAuthentication")

        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

And then in my `Main`:

```
Dim parameters As New OAuth2Parameters
If (DoAuthentication(strToken, parameters)) Then
    iResult = RESULT_SUCCESS_OAUTH
Else
    Return RESULT_FAILED_OAUTH
End If
```

It then continues. The problem is that sometimes, even though the "authenticate" succeeds so that it starts to run the rest of the code. that I then get an exception:

```
2020-11-30 18:47:03.6762|ERROR|GoogleAuthandSync.Program|AddEventsToCalendarXML|System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\XXXXX.Application\Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-user' because it is being used by another process.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

How can I authenticate / refresh the token and make sure we are ready to proceed so that this exception stops? It doesn't always happen.

(I renamed the token file for security in the code / error text above).

---

Should I be using the `Await` keyword?

[image]

```
If credential.Token.IsExpired(Google.Apis.Util.SystemClock.Default) Then
    Await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None)
End If
```

Would that make a difference? I notice that in this [sample code](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/IdentityModel.OidcClient.OidcClient.RefreshTokenAsync(string,%20object)/) they use `await`.

Comment: That is the file that stores the client credentials, for the user your application is logging in as **"user"**.  Is your application hanging some how?  I find it strange that it would be locked if the code has completed running previously.

Comment: @DaImTo The code proceeds to read in a XML data file, then (via batching) delete a range of calendar events before adding the calendar events. This tool is a console app which is called by the main application. My gut feeling is the token "refresh" function. Since it has to establish an updated token from the internet (as I understand it) I don't know if that correctly "waits" until it is ready to proceed with the rest of the app code.

Comment: Your welcome to post an issue over on the Google .net client library GitHub project.  This library has been stable for years i would be surprised to find that its broken.  You are using the standard FileDataStore which again i havent had a problem with in eight years.   I still think its an issue with you not waiting for your application to complete before starting a new one

Comment: @DalmTo But that is just it. Should we wait for the token file to be finished with? What if it is still being refreshed whilst we are then trying to use the calendar API? Only this console app uses the data store. Not the main application.

Comment: @DaImTo Asked here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1708

Comment: Have you tried adding `Await`, as you mentioned? Does the exception keep showing up? Also, have you noticed if there's any pattern for when this exception is thrown?

Comment: @Iamblichus We are in the middle of making tweaks to my app (including the adding of the `await` prefix, Once I have a complete working solution I will add a answer here with a summary of the important things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was encouraged to ask about the issue on GitHub (see [discussion](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1708)).

Turns out that I did not need to be using `RefreshTokenAsync` in the way that I was. I was able to simplify my code and turn it into an `Async` method liek this:

```
Private Async Function DoAuthenticationAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim credential As UserCredential
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets() With {
        .ClientId = m_strClientID,
        .ClientSecret = m_strClientSecret
    }

    Try
        credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, m_Scopes,
                                                             "user", CancellationToken.None,
                                                             New FileDataStore("XXXXX.Application"))

        ' Create the calendar service using an initializer instance
        Dim initializer As New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
            .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            .ApplicationName = "XXXXX"
        }

        m_Service = New CalendarService(initializer)

    Catch ex As Exception
        ' We encountered some kind of problem, perhaps they have not yet authenticated?
        ' Can we isolate that as the exception?
        m_logger.Error(ex, "DoAuthentication")

        Return False
    End Try

    Return True
End Function
```

Then, I had to move all of my code that was in the `Main` function into a task:

```
Private Async Function Run() As Task(Of Integer)
    ...
End Function
```

Finally, I adjusted `Main` like this:

```
Public Function Main() As Integer
    Return RunAsync.Result
End Function
```